# Why is pypy's clock() so imprecise?

Tags: python, pypy

I tried timing some of my code and noticed some really weird results with pypy. Look at this example:

```
from time import clock
from random import randint

times = []
for _ in range(10):
  start = clock()
  sum(i * i for i in range(randint(1000000, 2000000))) # waste time
  end = clock()
  times.append(int((end - start) * 1000000))

for t in times:
  print(t, "µs")
```

Running with `python3`, there's a bunch of random results, as expected:

```
506246 µs
461735 µs
403287 µs
472049 µs
651156 µs
609496 µs
467181 µs
633187 µs
562603 µs
744360 µs
```

Running with pypy, it seems that everything is only accurate to a third of a second:

```
43332 µs
36667 µs
30000 µs
23332 µs
19999 µs
23334 µs
26665 µs
20000 µs
36667 µs
26666 µs
```

Why is that?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo if you look at the variance in the numbers, you'll see that the pypy results are always aligned on 1/30 (not 1/3) second boundaries, unlike the Python3 results.

Comment: I'm not seeing these kinds of results. When I run this program on Windows 7 using Python 2.7, PyPy 2.4.0, and PyPy3 2.4.0, all of them appear to have the same randomness and precision (down to at least microseconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark's answer is correct in theory, but it is really a bug.  Please open a bug on the issue tracker of PyPy, specifying exactly which platform and PyPy version you're using (I seem to get the correct precision on Linux, and John on Windows).

Comment: I'm actually running on Arch Linux right now, so, I suppose that it's not that precise on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock):

> The precision, and in fact the very definition of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on that of the C function of the same name.

The precision will differ for different implementations. In this case pypy appears to be using a timer with a period of 1/30 second, so the precision will never be better than that.